# Filewatcher for the whole computer (alternative?)

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I want to write an application that gets events on every file change on the whole computer (to synchronize between file locations/permissions and my application's database).

I was thinking of using the .net filewatcher class but after some tests i found the following limitations:

1) The filewatcher has a buffer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.90).aspx):

> If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow.
>   This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory,
>   and it will only provide blanket notification. Increasing the size of
>   the buffer with the InternalBufferSize property is expensive, as it
>   comes from non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so
>   keep the buffer as small yet large enough to not miss any file change
>   events. To avoid a buffer overflow, use the NotifyFilter and
>   IncludeSubdirectories properties so you can filter out unwanted change
>   notifications.

So in the whole computer, I can get some large amount of events (in peak) that i need to handle.  Even if inside the event handling I'm only adding the event info to a queue I still can miss events.

2) Filewatcher has memory leaks:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/654232/filesystemwatcher-memory-leak
I checked it myself and it's true, after a few days my process memory grows from 20MB to 250MB

3) Microsoft says that we should use filewatcher for specific folders (I don't know why):

> Use FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in a specified directory.

So for these reasons i need an alternative solution to create my application. I know that I can write a driver but I prefer it to be a .net solution (based on win32 api, of course).

Thank you for your help,
Omri

Comment: Why not use [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642)?

Comment: I want to implement my own logic in C# in when the event happens, as far as i know filemon is a standalone software, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting monitoring (especially synchronous notifications) will slow down the system. You can probably make use of our CallbackFilter product which provides a driver and a handy .NET API for tracking file changes. And CallbackFilter supports asynchronous notifications which are faster. Discounted and free licenses are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this through WMI imo - the following link is relevant: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42212/WMI-and-File-System-Monitoring