# Watch on File System using FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#

I use `FileSystemWatcher` for watch on File System. it can watch on particular folder or drive.

But I want it on whole file system means it should watch on all drive.

Any idea about this ?

I do that much.

```
public static void Run()
{
     string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

     if (args.Length < 2)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe PATH [...] [PATH]");
          return;
     }
     List<string> list = new List<string>();
     for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
     {
          list.Add(args[i]);
     }

     foreach (string my_path in list)
     {
          WatchFile(my_path);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
     while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
}
private static void WatchFile(string watch_folder)
{
    watcher.Path = watch_folder;

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(convert);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

using [Filesystem Watcher - Multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635477/filesystem-watcher-multiple-folders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to Enumerate over all directories and watch all of them by using `FileSystemWatcher` on each of them.

But it will consume lots of resources. So you can, for an alternate look into this link:[Filewatcher for the whole computer (alternative?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196731/filewatcher-for-the-whole-computer-alternative)

Comment: You mean all `root` folders or all folders and subfolders(recursively)?

Answer (score 2):

You can watch entire system with using IncludeSubdirectories to Logical Drives.
Try this code,

```
string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

foreach(string drive in drives)
{
   FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
   watcher.Path = drive;
   watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
   watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

   watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

   watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
   watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
   watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
   watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

   watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```